# How to display the dropdown values based on other dropdown value using typescript in Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I am developing angular 2 application, in my current project I want the functionality for displaying dropdown values based on year, make, model. For example if I select Honda then display only Honda models in model dropdown.

By default I will bind the complete data for year, make and model.

This is my view.

[image]

**VehicleComponent.html**

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label  class="control-label">Year*</label><br />
        <select  friendly-name="Year" id="year" name="year" class="col-md-6 form-control"  ng-required="true" onchange='OnChange()' >
            <option>Select</option>
            
            <option *ngFor='let type of lookupdetailsvehicleyearinfo'>{{type.LookupValue}}</option>
           
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label  class="control-label">Make*</label><br />
        <select friendly-name="Make" class="col-md-6 form-control" ng-required="true" >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option *ngFor='let type of lookupdetailsvehiclemakeinfo'>{{type.LookupValue}}</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label  class="control-label">Model*</label>
        <select  friendly-name="Model" class="col-md-6 form-control" ng-required="true" >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option *ngFor='let type of lookupdetailsvehiclemodelinfo'>{{type.LookupValue}}</option>
           </select>
    </div>                                      
</div>
```

I will get the above data from My Own API's.

Can you please tell me how to write the typescript code in angular 2 application for the above functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is, track the `change` event of your select-input and change the source of another select-input. Angular2 will do the rest.

Using the selected `value`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <select (change)="firstDropDownChanged($event.target.value)" >
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor='let v of _values1'>{{ v }}</option>
      </select>

      <select >
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor='let v of _values2'>{{ v }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  private _values1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
  private _values2 = [];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  firstDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    console.log(val);

    if (val == "1") {
      this._values2 = ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3"];
    }
    else if (val == "2") {
      this._values2 = ["2.1", "2.2", "2.3"];
    }
    else if (val == "3") {
      this._values2 = ["3.1", "3.2", "3.3"];
    }
    else {
      this._values2 = [];
    }
  }
}
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/GDXsPt4aiS7vus6oPvuU?p=preview

**UPDATE**

Or you can use the `selectedIndex`:
 (note that `-1` cause your first "Select"-item.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <select (change)="firstDropDownChanged($event.target.selectedIndex - 1)" >
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let v of _values1">{{ v.val }}</option>
      </select>

      <select >
        <option>Select</option>
        <option *ngFor='let v of _values2'>{{ v }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  private _values1 = [
    { id: 1, val: "huhu" },
    { id: 2, val: "val2" },
    { id: 3, val: "yep" },
    { id: 4, val: "cool" }
  ];
  private _values2 = [];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  firstDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    const obj = this._values1[val];
    console.log(val, obj);

    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj.id == 1) {
      this._values2 = ["1.1", "1.2", "1.3"];
    }
    else if (obj.id == 2) {
      this._values2 = ["2.1", "2.2", "2.3"];
    }
    else if (obj.id == 3) {
      this._values2 = ["3.1", "3.2", "3.3"];
    }
    else {
      this._values2 = [];
    }
  }
}
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/wugNC6S27FB48EtRN906?p=preview

Comment: The above code works fine but for my scenario I need to check the if condition with ID in my collection not an value.

Comment: <option *ngFor='let type of lookupdetailsvehicleyearinfo' value="{{type.ID}}">{{type.LookupValue}}</option> by using this line of code I got the ID value but in the component file I check if condition with Selected Id in that if condition  I don't know how add the results to collection using typescript.

Comment: I wrote  below lines of code for adding one collection/array into other collection/array but it will override last value in the collection but not an added to the other collection, can you please tell me how to write the code for adding one collection to other collection.

        if (val == 5) {

            for (let make of this.lookupdetailsvehiclemakeinfo) {

                if (make.LookupDetailsCommonId == val ) {

                    this.lookupdetailsvehiclemakenewinfo = [make];
                }
         
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Ng5-Dynamic Selectoption - Drop down menu for selecting country then states then district

template.html

```html
<div>
    <h2>Hello country/ state/ cities </h2>

    <select (change)="countryChange($event)" >
      <option>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.country">{{ c.country }}</option>
    </select>

    <select (change)="statesChange($event)">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor='let state of states' [ngValue]="state.name">{{ state.name }}</option>
    </select>

    <select >
      <option>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor='let city of cities' [ngValue]="city">{{ city }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
var countries= [{
            "country": "Afghanistan",
      "states": [
                  { "name":"Nurestan", "cities":["c1", "c2", "c3"]  },
                  { "name":"Oruzgan", "cities":["orc1", "oruc2", "oruc3"] },
                  { "name":"Panjshir", "cities":["3c1", "3c2", "3c3"]  }
                ]
    },
    {
            "country": "Albania",
            "states": [ 
                  { "name": "Korce" , "cities":["c1", "c2", "c3"] },
                  { "name": "Kukes",  "cities":["orc1", "oruc2", "oruc3"] },
                  { "name": "Lezhe","cities":["orc1", "oruc2", "oruc3"]},
                  { "name": "Shkoder", "cities":["orc1", "oruc2", "oruc3"]},
                  { "name": "Tirane","cities":["orc1", "oruc2", "oruc3"]}
                ]
        },      
        {
            "country": "Antarctica",
            "states": []
        }           
    ]

    states= []; cities = [];
    countryChange(e){
      console.log(e.target.value)
      this.countries.filter(element => {
        if(element.country == e.target.value){
          console.log(element.states[0],"first state")
          this.states = element.states;
        }
      });
      this.cities = []
    }
    statesChange(evt){
      console.log(evt.target.value,this.states)
      this.states.filter( element =>{
        if(element.name == evt.target.value){
          this.cities = element.cities;
        }
      })
    }
```